# How to search within an xml data set?

Tags: php, javascript, xml

I have some xml data and I am trying to keyword search data. For example, if I search "some" for the following data it returns me the `<id>` and `<title>`.

```
<resource>
  <id>101</id>
  <title>Test Environment</title>
  <description><b>Some</b> description. </description>
  <type>classroom</type>
</resource>
<resource>
  <id>102</id>
  <title>ABC Test Environment</title>
  <description><b>Some</b> another description. </description>
  <type>classroom</type>
</resource>
...
```

I had a look on on xpath e.g. `$xml->xpath('//title')` but looks for elements only.

Basically what I need to do is to create a functionality where users can keyword search within the above data set which I receive from third party api in the above format. Any ideas how I can achieve this? using PHP/ Javascript etc.

Thanks.

Comment: You have PHP and JavaScript tags - I presume the JavaScript tag isn't really applicable (e.g. you are doing this server-side not client-side?)

Comment: I just wonder if there is any javascript solution there to achieve the required functionaity?

Comment: keyword search treats xml as a flat text file, maybe you willneed to search keyword in text nodes... what do you want to do really?

Comment: whatever way .. itdoesnt matter I just need to look for a keyword and retrieve min. the associated id (title, desc will help). I hope its clear.

Answer (score 1):

Xpath does let you search by the contents of the elements. A quick google search reveals this link: http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/org.w3c.dom/xpath_GetElemByText.html  which will get you right as rain in no time.

Comment: just did a quick test as per instructions on the page and looks like the answer. will give it another go and lt you know later. lso there is a comment on that page - In IE 8 this method of using path is not working?? I'll see.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

XPath does support this functionality, and it can be done on most [browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_parser.asp) (I assume this is a web application). However, are you sure this is what you would like to do? How much data will you be sending to the client?